# Convert value into lower case before knockout binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, data-binding

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/khs5zmpw/)

I bound a label with knockoutjs. The value bound always should be in lower case. While it will remain in uppercase in js model. How to do this ?

> Javascript

```
var model = { 
    name:ko.observable("Test") 
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

> HTML

```
<label data-bind="text:name">
```

Comment: `name().toLowerCase()` in your view simple . cheers

Comment: No, it should remain in uppercase inside viewmodel

Comment: it will but on view you will see in lowercase

Comment: I didnt get u . can you correct it in my fiddle link ?

Comment: @supercool - That doesn't work when the user edits the value in the input.

Comment: dont get confused with textbox. It may be label as well. Look my updated question

Comment: check the posted answer with fiddle .

Comment: data-bind='text: name().toLowerCase()' works for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you just need to use `toLowerCase` in the view

**view :**

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
     <p> name: <label data-bind='text: name().toLowerCase()'></label></p> 
</div>

<b>Original Value:
<pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($data,null,2)"></pre>
```

sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24730/)**

Comment: dare to explain . OP requested so .

Comment: You realise this reduces it to one-way binding, right? As in, when you change the text in the textbox it no longer updates the model.

Comment: yes i do but used said it can be a label . so i done like that .

Comment: Thanks super cool. Actually i had tried name.toLowerCase() .And your code works for me.

Comment: @Jamiec i made it label to avoid further misunderstanding . cheers and rightly pointed so .

Comment: @MotaChuha you should use `()` to read a observable value . @T.J agreed mate .

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you want to do, in particular when the value is coming *from* the textarea, but you can probably do whatever it is using a writable computed:

```
model.lowerName = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return model.name().toLowerCase();
    },
    write: function(newValue) {
        // ...save this however it is you want to save it...
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value:lowerName">
```

---

Re your updated question: Your update **completely** changes the question. If you don't need updates from the element and are only *showing* what's in `name`, you have two options:

1. A read-only computed:

   ```
   model.lowerName = ko.pureComputed(function() { return model.name().toLowerCase(); });
   ```

   HTML:

   ```
   <label data-bind="text:lowerName"></label>
   ```
2. Just do it in the binding:

   ```
   <label data-bind="text:name().toLowerCase()"></label>
   ```

Comment: @mattytommo: Well, *someone* is missing the point. Again, `value` is a two-way binding. So a question [**stating** that binding](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30888954/1) is about two-way handling. No assumptions, no inferring. Also no flaming, I was just asking the OP to be clear about what they wanted. Which they've now done.